# TensorFlow1.13 can't use slice_input_producer

Tags: tensorflow

My TensorFlow's version is 1.13.1. When I used `tf.train.slice_input_producer`, I got a warning message:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:55: slice_input_producer (from tensorflow.python.training.input) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a warning message. As per the official tensorflow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/slice_input_producer),

> Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future
>   version. Instructions for updating: Queue-based input pipelines have
>   been replaced by tf.data. Use
>   tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tuple(tensor_list)).shuffle(tf.shape(input_tensor,
>   out_type=tf.int64)[0]).repeat(num_epochs). If shuffle=False, omit the
>   .shuffle(...).

In a nutshell, it basically says `tf.train.slice_input_producer()` is deprecated and no longer used. In place of that, you should use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`.